# How to add Default Fallback intents in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I imported a prebuilt Support agent in dialogflow and don't seed Default Welcome and Fallback Intents. I found that Welcome Intent can be created by myself by adding the WELCOME event into the events list. But how Fallback can be created?

I looked into official documentation (https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/default-intents) and doesn't show any way to add Fallback Intent. There is not a Fallback event also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the intents page there are three dots besides `Create Intent` button, when you click on it there will be option `Create Fallback Intent`.

It will behave like universal fallback intent which you want.
If you want it to act only in certain conditions then you need to define `input contexts` as well.
Please note that no two fallback intents can have same input contexts.

Hope it helps.